# Python вытащить из словаря значения переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, словари, переменные

```
{"status":"success","result":[
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0431\u0430\u043d","username":"Akkermanov"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"250 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 40 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Ferrari_benz"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"100 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 15 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Feather_YT"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"20 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 0 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"pipo_pirat498"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"20 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 0 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Hallker_YT"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"100 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 15 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Johny_LayYT"}]}
```

Нужно вытащить значения name и username
И желательно в формате

name1: \u0420\u0430\u0437\u0431\u0430\u043d
username1: Akkermanov

name2: 250 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 40 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]
username2: Ferrari_benz

name3: 100 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 15 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]
username3: Feather_YT

name4: 20 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 0 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]
username4: pipo_pirat498

name5: ...
username5: ...
name6: ...
username6: ...

Я совсем новичок, поэтому пожалуйста максимально просто для понимания

Вот полный код

```
from requests import request
import time
n = 1
while True:
    t = request('GET', 'https://sunmc.ru/last-purchases').text
    with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(t)
        n=n+1
        temp = t["result"]
        index = 1
        for i in temp:
            print("name{}:".format(index), i["name"], end=" ")
            print("username{}:".format(index), i["username"])
            index += 1
            time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: а html-код где? пока я вижу вложенный словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {"status":"success","result":[
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":u"\u0420\u0430\u0437\u0431\u0430\u043d","username":"Akkermanov"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"250 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 40 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Ferrari_benz"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"100 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 15 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Feather_YT"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"20 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 0 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"pipo_pirat498"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"20 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 0 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Hallker_YT"},
{"picture":"data:image\/png;base64,","name":"100 \u0420\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439 [\u0411\u043e\u043d\u0443\u0441 - 15 \u0440\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0435\u0439]","username":"Johny_LayYT"}]}

temp =  a["result"]
index = 1
for i in temp:
    print("name{}:".format(index), i["name"], end=" ")
    print("username{}:".format(index), i["username"])
    index += 1
```

**Вывод:**

```
name1: Разбан username1: Akkermanov
name2: 250 Рублей [Бонус - 40 рублей] username2: Ferrari_benz
name3: 100 Рублей [Бонус - 15 рублей] username3: Feather_YT
name4: 20 Рублей [Бонус - 0 рублей] username4: pipo_pirat498
name5: 20 Рублей [Бонус - 0 рублей] username5: Hallker_YT
name6: 100 Рублей [Бонус - 15 рублей] username6: Johny_LayYT
```

**Или так, без декодирования символов unicode:**

```
temp =  a["result"]
index = 1
for i in temp:
    i["name"].replace("\\","\\")
    print("name{}:".format(index), i["name"].encode('raw_unicode_escape'), end=" ")
    print("username{}:".format(index), i["username"])
    index += 1
```

**вывод будет таким:**

```
name1: b'\\u0420\\u0430\\u0437\\u0431\\u0430\\u043d' username1: Akkermanov
name2: b'250 \\u0420\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439 [\\u0411\\u043e\\u043d\\u0443\\u0441 - 40 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439]' username2: Ferrari_benz
name3: b'100 \\u0420\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439 [\\u0411\\u043e\\u043d\\u0443\\u0441 - 15 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439]' username3: Feather_YT
name4: b'20 \\u0420\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439 [\\u0411\\u043e\\u043d\\u0443\\u0441 - 0 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439]' username4: pipo_pirat498
name5: b'20 \\u0420\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439 [\\u0411\\u043e\\u043d\\u0443\\u0441 - 0 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439]' username5: Hallker_YT
name6: b'100 \\u0420\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439 [\\u0411\\u043e\\u043d\\u0443\\u0441 - 15 \\u0440\\u0443\\u0431\\u043b\\u0435\\u0439]' username6: Johny_LayYT
```

Comment: `from requests import request
import time

n = 1
while True:
    t = request('GET', 'https://sunmc.ru/last-purchases').text
    with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(t)
        n=n+1
        temp = t["result"]
        index = 1
        for i in temp:
            print("name{}:".format(index), i["name"], end=" ")
            print("username{}:".format(index), i["username"])
            index += 1
        time.sleep(1000)`


TypeError: string indices must be integers
Меняю тип переменной все-равно ругается, что делать ?

Comment: Я запустил этот код, у меня ошибок нет.

Comment: я прикрепил код к основному вопросу (в конце), у меня что где-то нет/лишняя сноска ? Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Теперь понятно. По запросу t = request('GET', 'https://sunmc.ru/last-purchases').tex, ты получаешь string, а не словарь. Поэтому этот код конечно не подойдет. То есть тупо строка символов.  Этот компот нужно еще распарсивать, например с помощью BeautifulSoup, так что изучай.